# Java applet only partially paints

Tags: java, drawing, buffer, render, paint

I'm new to Java applet programming, so excuse me if this is a very basic question, but I've googled it extensively and have only found semi-related problems and solutions.

I'm writing a simple demonstration of some geometric algorithms, and when I `repaint()`, only some of my graphics primitives are rendered to the screen.  Every time my applet redraws, a seemingly random subset of my lines and ellipses are painted.  The only pattern to it is that the primitives that *are* rendered are always from the beginning of the drawing.  I.E, sometimes it will draw primitives 0-2, sometimes 0-5, sometimes the whole batch.

I would like to point out that, as far as I can tell, this is not the classic "flickering" that can be solved with double-bufferring.  To my understanding, flickering is when for short periods of time you can see a partially rendered applet before it finishes rendering.  In my case, however, if it doesn't finish rendering, it *never* finishes unless I `redraw()` again and get lucky.  I've tried double buffering:

```
public void update(Graphics g) {
    Graphics offgc;
    Image offscreen = null;
    Dimension d = size();

    // create the offscreen buffer and associated Graphics
    offscreen = createImage(d.width, d.height);
    offgc = offscreen.getGraphics();
    // clear the exposed area
    offgc.setColor(getBackground());
    offgc.fillRect(0, 0, d.width, d.height);
    offgc.setColor(getForeground());
    // do normal redraw
    paint(offgc);
    // transfer offscreen to window
    g.drawImage(offscreen, 0, 0, this);
}
```

But it doesn't seem to help at all.  If it's useful, here's some pics of what's happening.  This is what it's supposed to look like:

[image: full]

But most of the time it looks something like this:

[image: partial1]

or this:

[image: partial2]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Its not applet issue i suppose. Did you try to use `JFrame` and see the same problem?

Comment: Don't use update to render the results, you should be using ain't to paint the off screen buffer. The offscreen buffer should be update independently of the paint process and simply painted as needed. You really need to override the paint methods of to level containers, instead using something like JPanel add overriding its paintComponent method instead

Comment: `JFrame` in what place in the application?  Sorry, I'm quite new to Java.  Wouldn't `JFrame` be incompatible with the AWT components I'm using?

Answer (score 1):

This isn't really how double buffering should work, no is it how the paint process works.

- Don't override `update`.
- Don't override `paint` of top level containers (like Applet/JApplet/Frame/JFrame) where possible
- Use a "paint" panel onto which you can render, preferably something like `JPanel`.  Swing components provide double buffering support
- A double buffer should be painted on out side the paint cycle and only updated when needed, this makes the overall paint process faster as you're not having re-render the content unnecessarily.
- When it comes time to update the buffer, render to a temp buffer first, this ensures that any repaints that might occur while you're updating aren't reflected back to the screen prematurely...

[image]

```
public class TestPaintGeometry {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TestPaintGeometry();
    }

    public TestPaintGeometry() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
                } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
                } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
                } catch (UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                frame.add(new ShowPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class ShowPane extends JPanel {

        private GeometryPane geoPane;

        public ShowPane() {
            setLayout(new BorderLayout());

            geoPane = new GeometryPane();
            JButton redrew = new JButton("Redraw");
            add(geoPane);
            add(redrew, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
            redrew.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    geoPane.redrew();
                }
            });
        }            
    }

    public class GeometryPane extends JPanel {

        private BufferedImage buffer;

        public void redrew() {
            Path2D.Float path = new Path2D.Float();
            int width = getWidth();
            int height = getHeight();

            int points = Math.max(10, (int) Math.round(Math.random() * 100));
            for (int index = 0; index < points; index++) {
                int x = (int) Math.round(Math.random() * width);
                int y = (int) Math.round(Math.random() * height);
                if (index > 0) {
                    path.lineTo(x, y);
                } else {
                    path.moveTo(x, y);
                }
            }

            BufferedImage tmp = createCompatibleImage(width, height);
            Graphics2D g2d = tmp.createGraphics();
            g2d.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            g2d.draw(path);
            g2d.dispose();

            buffer = tmp;
            repaint();
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(200, 200);
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            if (buffer != null) {
                int x = (getWidth() - buffer.getWidth()) / 2;
                int y = (getHeight() - buffer.getHeight()) / 2;
                g.drawImage(buffer, x, y, this);
            }
        }
    }

    public static GraphicsConfiguration getGraphicsConfiguration() {
        return GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getDefaultScreenDevice().getDefaultConfiguration();
    }

    public static BufferedImage createCompatibleImage(int width, int height) {
        return createCompatibleImage(width, height, Transparency.TRANSLUCENT);
    }

    public static BufferedImage createCompatibleImage(int width, int height, int transparency) {
        BufferedImage image = getGraphicsConfiguration().createCompatibleImage(width, height, transparency);
        image.coerceData(true);
        return image;
    }
}
```

This allows you deploy the `GeometryPane` to a `JFrame` or `JAppelt` as it's not constrained by the legacy of it's inheritance...

Comment: Thanks!  That `update()` quick-fix was based on something I found on google - guess I shouldn't always trust every solution I read to be a good idea.  So, to be clear, the simplest solution for the future (IE not constrained by what's already been written in a project) is to have your `Applet` subclass be a small class containing a large `JFrame` subclass that handles what I'm using the applet for (except overriding `paintComponent()`, not `paint()`)?  That `TestPaintGeometry` example you gave is only to strap on to existing applets, right?

Comment: No.  `JApplet` and `JFrame` are what are known as top level containers, they show other components/containers on the screen, you should avoid mixing them.  Use a something like `JPanel` to produce the UI you want, mixing in other components as needed, then you can add it either to a `JFrame` or a `JApplet` depending on your needs.  Where possible, avoid AWT components and stick to Swing.